# onclick show all hidden elements

Tags: javascript, show-hide

On click of the different letters the following code is showing the corresponding elements. But I'm struggling to to show all elements when someone clicks "All".

How could I achieve this?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active"
  } 
}
```

```html
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'A')">A</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'B')">B</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'C')">C</a> &nbsp;
<div id="A" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <a href="">Abschreibung</a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="B" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>B</h3>
  <a href="">Bauvorhaben</a>
</div>
<div id="C" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>C</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no element with `id` *`defaultOpen`*

Comment: yes sorry, copied too much, edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
```

So the problem is this line errors out when the "cityName" argument is "All".
So you just need to handle that scenario, and whenever you get "All" in that variable you can instead display all elements.

I have fixed the code in snippet below:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  if (cityName != 'All') {
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // Display all
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  if (evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").className += " active"
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'A')">A</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'B')">B</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'C')">C</a> &nbsp;
<div id="A" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <a href="">Abschreibung</a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="B" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>B</h3>
  <a href="">Bauvorhaben</a>
</div>
<div id="C" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>C</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the condition for which the parameter is all and not anything else. If it is anything else then display that id. Added a switch statement. Loop over every class and display them when "All" is clicked, else add a default option and first hide everything and display what is clicked.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")).forEach(ele => ele.classList.remove('active'))
  evt.target.classList.add('active')
  switch (cityName) {
    case "All":
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")).forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'block')
      break;
    default:
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")).forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'none');
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = 'block'
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'All')">All</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'A')">A</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'B')">B</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'C')">C</a> &nbsp;
<div id="A" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <a href="">Abschreibung</a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="B" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>B</h3>
  <a href="">Bauvorhaben</a>
</div>
<div id="C" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>C</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a separate function for the all and just loop through the tab content divs to show them all:

```js
function openAll() {
  // show all tab content divs
  var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  
  // add active class to all as they are all open
  var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.add("active");
  }
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  } 
}
```

```css
.tabcontent {
 display:none;
}

.active {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openAll()">All</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'A')">A</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'B')">B</a>
<a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'C')">C</a> &nbsp;
<div id="A" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <a href="">Abschreibung</a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="B" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>B</h3>
  <a href="">Bauvorhaben</a>
</div>
<div id="C" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>C</h3>
</div>
```

I would also use `.classList` to add and remove classes properly (rather than appending and then replacing them)